# Changing format of biblatex-chicago for entries with Japanese

Tags: biblatex-chicago, xecjk

I am trying to adjust the biblatex-chicago output formatting slightly, in order to realize a format close to the one specified in the [Monumenta Nipponica Style Sheet](http://dept.sophia.ac.jp/monumenta/pdf/MN-Style-Sheet.pdf), by using the *nameaddon* and *titleaddon* fields for the respective Japanese entries.

Basically my goals are to (see image below):
1. Remove the square brackets around the *nameaddon* field.
2. Remove the dot after the *title* field, **but only in the case that a *titleaddon* field is specified**.

[image]

For the example, using xeCJK, I have downloaded the "NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular.otf" font [here](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-jpan). I have found many questions which mention solutions close to this problem, but I was not able to apply these solutions to my problem.

Any help or hints to solutions to this problem would be very much appreciated.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular.otf}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{Hattori.1986,
 author = {Hattori, Yukio},
 date = {1986},
 title = {Ōinaru koya: kinsei toshi no shukusai kūkan},
 address = {Tōkyō},
 publisher = {Heibonsha},
 nameaddon = {服部幸雄},
 titleaddon = {大いなる小屋：近世都市の祝祭空間},
}
@book{Ernst.1974,
 author = {Ernst, Earle},
 date = {1974},
 title = {The Kabuki theatre},
 address = {Honolulu},
 publisher = {{University of Hawaii Press}},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{Intended outcome:} 

\noindent Hattori, Yukio 服部幸雄. 1986. \textit{Ōinaru koya: kinsei toshi no shukusai kūkan} 大いなる小屋：近世都市の祝祭空間. Tōkyō: Heibonsha \\
\medskip

\noindent \textbf{Test:} 

\noindent \citet{Hattori.1986} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Good MWE with `filecontents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can be solved with `\DeclareFieldFormat{nameaddon}{#1}`.
2. Should be solved by setting the option `ptitleaddon=space`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifCJKjp-Regular.otf}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,natbib,ptitleaddon=space]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldFormat{nameaddon}{#1}%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hattori.1986,
 author = {Hattori, Yukio},
 date = {1986},
 title = {Ōinaru koya: kinsei toshi no shukusai kūkan},
 address = {Tōkyō},
 publisher = {Heibonsha},
 nameaddon = {服部幸雄},
 titleaddon = {大いなる小屋：近世都市の祝祭空間},
}
@book{Ernst.1974,
 author = {Ernst, Earle},
 date = {1974},
 title = {The Kabuki theatre},
 address = {Honolulu},
 publisher = {{University of Hawaii Press}},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Intended outcome:} 

\noindent Hattori, Yukio 服部幸雄. 1986. \textit{Ōinaru koya: kinsei toshi no shukusai kūkan} 大いなる小屋：近世都市の祝祭空間. Tōkyō: Heibonsha \\
\medskip

\noindent \textbf{Test:} 

\noindent \citet{Hattori.1986} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hattori, Yukio 服部幸雄. 1986. Ōinaru koya: kinsei toshi no shukusai kūkan 大いなる小屋：近世都市の祝祭空間. Tōkyō: Heibonsha.]

Comment: That's it. Wonderful. Thank you for the answer.